# Evaluate glmtree model

Tags: r, party

I am using the `glmtree` function from the `partykit` package in R.

I would like to know how I can evaluate the models and how I can improve them.

I am growing a big tree (`alpha = 0.9`) and pruning with AIC as the criterion.
I am using the AUC (`pROC` package) and the results are between 0.62 and 0.79.

```
fit <- glmtree(fD ~ 1 | Age + fGender + Qualification + fOccupation + SizeWorkplc,
  data = newdata, family = "binomial",
  minsize = 50, maxdepth = 4, alpha = 0.9, prune = "AIC")

prob <- predict(fit, newdata = newdata, type "response")
newdata$prob <- prob
g <- roc(fD ~ prob, data = newdata)
plot(g)
```

I am really new on this, so I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 4):

The strategy you describe looks very reasonable. For evaluation you can use the usual kinds of measures that you employ for other binary classiers (or trees in particular): misclassification rate (or conversely classification accuracy), log-likelihood, ROC, AUC, etc. Personally, I often use the `ROCR` package but the `pROC` package you used appears to offer useful tools for this as well.

For improving the model, you might consider whether extending the model part from an intercept (`fD ~ 1`) to something with a regressor. I would recommend to do so based on subject-matter knowledge which I presume you have for this analysis. If, for example, you suspect that the `Qualification` effect or the `Age` effect depends on interactions with the remaining variables than you could use `fD ~ Age + Qualification | fGender + fOccupation + SizeWorkplc` or something like this. The the choice of the model certainly depends on what you could interpret or which interactions you would want to assess.

Comment: Thank you very much, Achim. Do you know how can I get confidence intervals for the `glmtree` predictions?

Comment: With a little bit of glue code: For example with `data("kyphosis", package = "rpart")` you can fit `m <- glmtree(Kyphosis ~ 1 | Start + Age + Number, data = kyphosis, family = binomial)` and then `predict(m, kyphosis, type = "response")`. For the associated standard errors, you need a small helper function, say `sefit <- function(object, newdata) predict(object, newdata, se.fit = TRUE)$se.fit` that you can then pass on to `predict(m, kyphosis, type = sefit)`. Whether or not these standard errors are really still valid (after selection of the tree), is a different question, though.

Comment: Thank you very much Achim for your help. Do you know if I can apply the glmtree to an ordinal variable? If yes, which family should I use? If not, do you know another tree-based model that I could use? Thank you once again!

Comment: Ordinal data is not supported by `glmtree()`. We're currently working on a combination of the general `mob()` infrastructure with `polr()` and/or `clm()`. The fitting of the tree is realtively easy and straightforward but we haven't finished all the nice glue code for plotting and predictions etc. If you want to use a constant-fit tree (with only partitioning variables but no regressor variables), I would recommend to use `ctree()` which deals with ordered factor responses.

Comment: That would be great! Do you have any idea when it would be finished? Is it possible to fit a multinomial logistic with the `glmtree()`? I will try the `ctree()`. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Is there any pruning method to `ctree()` for large data sets (similar to AIC/BIC-based post-pruning)? And if I have regressor variables, what would you suggest?

Comment: No automatic pruning procedure is currently available for `ctree()`. In principle, AIC- or BIC-based pruning could be applied but there is no ready-made function for it. As for the planned extensions: In the `partykit` project on R-Forge (https://R-Forge.R-project.org/R/?group_id=261) there is some _very rough_ code but it will need further work before being officially released. There is no fixed timeline, yet.